# Which is the proper way to wait for an API call to complete before calling a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a react app with Firebase cloud functions. There is an API call in the cloud function and it takes time for it to complete.

Here is my functions:

```
exports.whatThreeWords = functions.firestore
.document('locations/{locationId}')
.onCreate((doc, context) => {
  const locData = doc.data();
  const locId = context.params.locationId;

  const converted = api.convertToCoordinates('///location.location.location')
  .then(data => console.log(data.coordinates))
  const addr= {
    address : `${converted.coordinates}`, 
    id : locId
  }
  return createAddress(addr)
})

const createAddress = (async addr => {
  const doc = await admin.firestore().collection('addr').add(addr);
  return console.log('created', doc);
})
```

When I do this, the createAddress() function runs before the API call is complete.

When I put the function call inside of the API call, I get an error saying function returned undefined

```
  const converted = api.convertToCoordinates('///walnuts.flash.potential')
  .then((data) => {
  const addr= {
    address : `${converted.coordinates}`, 
    id : locId
  }
return createAddress(addr)
})
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return from the function after you have received the API response.

```js
exports.whatThreeWords = functions.firestore
.document('locations/{locationId}')
.onCreate((doc, context) => {
  const locData = doc.data();
  const locId = context.params.locationId;

  return api.convertToCoordinates('///location.location.location')
  .then(converted => {
    //console.log(data.coordinates)
      const addr= {
        address : `${converted.coordinates}`, 
        id : locId
      }
      return createAddress(addr)
  })
})
```

Alternatively you can use async await syntax:

```js
exports.whatThreeWords = functions.firestore
.document('locations/{locationId}')
.onCreate(async (doc, context) => {
  //      ^^^^^
  const locData = doc.data();
  const locId = context.params.locationId;

  const converted = await api.convertToCoordinates('///location.location.location')
    //console.log(data.coordinates)
  const addr= {
    address : `${converted.coordinates}`, 
    id : locId
  }
  return createAddress(addr)
})

const createAddress = async addr => {
  const doc = await admin.firestore().collection('addr').add(addr);
  return console.log('created', doc);
}
```